# How to request data to be deleted using the button in PHP

Tags: php, database, button, sql-delete

Hello im newbie in programming, i wanna ask a question

I have a problem calling the data from the button, my plan is want to take the id of one of the products, then i call it using `$ _REQUEST` function, but when I implement it, the product is not deleted, did I miss something? Can you help me?

there is my code

```
<td class="delete"><button type="submit" name="delete" title="delete" value="delete" >x</button></td>

<?php } 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {               
        $id = $objectModel->getData('SELECT product_id from products where product_name ="'. $data['product_name'] . '"');
        $id = $id[0]['product_id'];
        $deleted = $objectModel->getConnection()->query('DELETE from price where product_id = "'. $id . '" AND cg_id = "'.$data['customer_group'].'"');     
         // var_dump($id);                  
    }     
    
?>
```

the `var_dump(isset($id))`  said `string(2) "17"`

can you help me?

Comment: Where does $data comefrom?

Comment: Is `var_dump($id);` what you expect?

Comment: the $data comefrom objectModel where i select the data sir like Select * from table, 
and the var_dump($id); i used for checking the data whether read or not sir

Comment: But _what are those values_?

Comment: Oh, thats number 2 is data array in number 2, and the 17 is the products id, in this case is my sql is readable correctly, but the problem is why can't it be deleted?

Comment: Either `$id` is not the value you expect, `$data['customer_group']` is not the value you expect, there is no row in that table with both of those ids, or there's an error in the sql like a wrong column name etc

Comment: Can you please show your full html form and the code where you define `$data`?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM price
INNER JOIN customer_group ON customer_group.cg_id = price.cg_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = price.product_id
ORDER BY product_name ASC"; `


`$Model = new Model();
$query = $Model->getData($sql);
$data = $query;`


`foreach ($data as $data) {` 

theres the `$data` i got sir @RobinGillitzer

Comment: Please try to use another name for the second `$data` in the foreach. It overrides after the foreach. Like: `foreach ($data as $item) {` Whats is the result of `var_dump($data['customer_group']);`?